# mat-paginator breaks when mat-table is inside of NgIf

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table, angular-material-paginator

I have an angular project that is using `mat-table` and `mat-paginator` for a certain view, the problem is the view has a grid view and table view with a toggle, the grid view is default and table is hidden using an NgIf when the grid view is active.  If I set the default to the table view then pagination works fine unless I swap to grid view and back, if the default if set to grid it breaks when I swap to the table view.  I'm guessing its because the table is hidden when this code runs:

```
this.sliceList = new MatTableDataSource<Slice>(result);
this.sliceList.paginator = this.paginator;
```

I tried console logging `this.sliceList` and `sliceList.paginator` is undefined when the grid view is defaulted  so I assuming this is the issue.  How Can I fix this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

according to this [thread](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10205),try use [hidden] instead of *ngIf.

```
<div [hidden]="condition">
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  ...
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

Comment: work in my case thank you

Answer (score 11):

**1st Solution**

Move mat-paginator from inside *ngIf div to outside

**2nd Solution**

use static false while declaring MatPaginator or MatSort

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;
```

Comment: In my case I used 2nd solution but with
`this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(my_data);`
 `setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator);` 
and it works

Answer (score 2):

For me I was using like this
**Code Before:**

```
 <div *ngIf="tableData?.data.length > 0; else noData">
      <mat-table [dataSource]="tableData" class="table-margin-0">
            ........
      </mat-table>
      <mat-paginator
            [pageSizeOptions]="[6, 10, 25, 50, 100]"
            showFirstLastButtons
      ></mat-paginator>
 </div>
```

Now using like this,
by adding `[hidden]` in paginator **outside the `*ngIf`** that works for me

Here is the code that worked
**Code after:**

```
<div *ngIf="tableData?.data.length > 0; else noData">
      <mat-table [dataSource]="tableData" class="table-margin-0">
            ........
      </mat-table>
 </div>
<mat-paginator
      [hidden]="tableData?.data.length === 0"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[6, 10, 25, 50, 100]"
      showFirstLastButtons
 ></mat-paginator>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solve my problem in ANgular 10

Setting static to False does the trick.

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.matTableConfig.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.matTableConfig.dataSource);
          this.matTableConfig.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.matTableConfig.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after some research I was able to make it work using the @ViewChild annotation and a set function.

In my component.ts file:

```
  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  private paginator: MatPaginator;
  /*
   We are using @ViewChild because of the ngIf with async pipe on the template
   When the data is emmited for the first time from the observable, we need to bind the
   pagination component with the datasource. This can be achieved with the code bellow.
  */
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    if(mp) {
      this.paginator = mp;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(your_data);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
     }
   }
```

and in my template file:

```
  // my observable with the async pipe
  <div *ngIf="raceList$ | async as races">
    <div class="mat-table-width">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      ...
      </table>
      <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 30]"
                      showFirstLastButtons
                      aria-label="select page of races">
      </mat-paginator>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That is almost correct. The function cdRef.detectChanges() must be executed before the paginator is set. Otherwise the changes will not be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Create in file.html the `<div>` with these IDs:

```html
div id="dataFound" style="display:none;"
div id="dataNotFound" style="display:none;"
```

In file.ts

```
document.getElementById("dataFound").style.display = 'none';    /* ngIf = false     
document.getElementById("dataNotFound").style.display = 'inline'; /* ngIf = true
```

Answer (score 0):

loaddata hinders the funtionality of the mat paginator due to which ng if does not works in this condition . instead of using *ngIf use [hidden] = "condition on which u want to hide"